# Migrating CCK fields

Tags: 7, migrations, entities, upgrading

I'm in the process of upgrading to Drupal 7.12 from Drupal 6.25.
I have been upgrading all my modules as well, and now is time to figure out how to migrate the data from CCK to D7 Fields.

I found the [Migrating D6 Content Construction Kit (CCK) to D7 Fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/1144136) article, which explains how to do this.

Unfortunately I after I update the CCK module, and enable the Content Migrate Module, I don't see where the Content Migrate Module under Admin -> Structure -> Content Migrate!

I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Before I could run the CCK migration I needed to run the `mywebsite.com/update.php` script before I could use the Migrate Fields.

That solved my issue.

Comment: Running update.php just once is usually not sufficient. Follow the instructions in UPGRADE.txt carefully, or use the Drush Site Upgrade command.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [Drush Site Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_sup) command. It automatically converted my CCK fields to D7 fields core module.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/drush_sup

Answer (score 1):

Download and enable the contributed [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module (eg using Drush).

For further information about how to use this module, read its [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/415260).